# Why is Belarus called "White Russia"?

Tags: translation, etymology, word

In Chinese Belarus is `白俄罗斯`, which literally means `White Russia`. But I don't understand why it is called as such.

If you get more rigorous with the pronunciation, it is more like `be`, but since there seems to be no word to be pronunced `be` in Chinese, maybe `bei` might be preferrable. So `呗俄罗斯` or something like that.

Also why is it not more direct, such as `被拉入式` or something like that?

Is this related to some historical or political reasons? (Especially because `黑` is considered a bad word)

Comment: wiki has four possible answers: https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%99%BD%E4%BF%84%E7%BD%97%E6%96%AF

Comment: Belarus means White Russia in Russian!

Comment: Related: [Did the name "白俄罗斯" exist in Chinese before 1991?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/27489)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the name is also translated according to its original meaning.

> 白俄罗斯在本土语言中是Беларусь，其中前面的Бела是“白“的意思，剩下的是“罗斯”的意思。

`白` comes from the front part of the original phrase `Беларусь`, i.e. `Бела`, which means `white`.

and

> 白俄罗斯人是东斯拉夫人的一支，根本不属于俄罗斯民族。白俄罗斯人称自己为“别拉罗斯”（音）人，如果完全按照音译国名就是“别拉罗斯”。“别拉罗斯”的俄语翻译是
>   Беларусь 由“Бела”（白色）和русь（罗斯）两部分组成。应该翻译为“白罗斯”。
>
> 英语可能是从俄语再译，是 belarussia 。可能是因为当时的翻译者，从英文的russia联想到俄罗斯，又因为俄文中的 Бела
>   （白色），再加上对白俄罗斯人的历史没有常识，就想当然地翻译为“白俄罗斯”了。

references:
[【风俗文化】其实，每一个“斯坦”国都有自己名字的由来](http://russian.dbw.cn/system/2015/05/25/000975350.shtml)
[国名的疑问为什么叫白俄罗斯?因为他的人比俄罗斯还白?](https://www.lookmw.cn/doc/ekkwni.html)
[俄罗斯、白俄罗斯、乌克兰等名称的由来及其它](http://www.docin.com/p-1121235499.html)

Comment: 從發音上看，這既是意譯也是音譯。

Comment: I don't think it's a translation mistake. They call themselves "white russia", why can't we translate into white+russia?

Comment: @jf328 Because the "correct" translation (音译) might be "白罗斯". If we don't consider about the conformance that "Russia" is translated as "俄罗斯", "belarussia" should be translated directly as "白罗斯". [Here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/19468/4072) is another question which might be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Беларусь = Белая + Русь

Русь - is a short and ancient word for Russia.

Бела - is a short adjective of Белая which is white.