# Did the name "白俄罗斯" exist in Chinese before 1991?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

Did the name "白俄罗斯" for Belarus exist in Chinese language before 1991 or was it created only when Belarus became an independent state in 1991?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the internet archive has the book 瀛環志畧, in volume 4, **"白峩"** was used to translate belarus:

https://archive.org/stream/02087085.cn#page/n43/mode/1up

[image: pic]

this book was published in 1849.

the 峩 (u+5ce9) was a variant of 峨 (u+5ce8), both of them share the same pronunciation with the character 俄 (u+4fc4), that is used in modern days translation.

then, the internet archive has another book 海國圖志, in volume 54, **"白峩羅斯"** was used in lieu of belarus:

https://archive.org/stream/02087117.cn#page/n50/mode/1up

[image]

this book was published in 1843, maybe the first geographic / atlas type of book in imperial china.

btw, minsk was translated as "閔士其" :)

have fun :)

Comment: indeed, if you can read literary chinese, the volume 56 mentioned many books about "russia", i guess some of them would talk about belarus.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it already existed. Prior to the present-day republic,
 there was the [Belarusian People's Republic](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%99%BD%E4%BF%84%E7%BE%85%E6%96%AF%E4%BA%BA%E6%B0%91%E5%85%B1%E5%92%8C%E5%9C%8B), the [Socialist Soviet Republic of Byelorussia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%99%BD%E4%BF%84%E7%BE%85%E6%96%AF%E7%A4%BE%E6%9C%83%E4%B8%BB%E7%BE%A9%E8%98%87%E7%B6%AD%E5%9F%83%E5%85%B1%E5%92%8C%E5%9C%8B), and the [Byelorussian Soviet Socialist Republic](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%99%BD%E4%BF%84%E7%BD%97%E6%96%AF%E8%8B%8F%E7%BB%B4%E5%9F%83%E7%A4%BE%E4%BC%9A%E4%B8%BB%E4%B9%89%E5%85%B1%E5%92%8C%E5%9B%BD). All of the official Chinese names for these states/provinces include 白俄罗斯. There seem to be [pre-1991 Chinese books that use the term](https://books.google.com/books?id=_DtSAQAAMAAJ&q=%E7%99%BD%E4%BF%84%E7%BD%97%E6%96%AF&dq=%E7%99%BD%E4%BF%84%E7%BD%97%E6%96%AF&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin6t-4xrLXAhWCLmMKHXApBBwQ6AEIWjAI), but Google Books is not a perfect source.

Comment: @brilliant, google books has [some results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E7%99%BD%E4%BF%84%E7%BD%97%E6%96%AF&hl=en&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A1989&tbm=bks). It's hard to say if some of them might be recent translations into Chinese of works originally published earlier, though.